# Setting up push notification for windows phone. MPNS and its role

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx

This is the API documentation of the push notification service I want to get pushes from: https://developers.podio.com/examples/push

How do I go about implementing push notifications with Podio if they do not support MPNS. It looks like (from the msdn documentation) that they will have to send the notifications to Microsoft Push Notification Service at stage 5.

Is there a way around this stage? Can I communicate directly with Podios PNS somehow? Why should Podio who are protected by Citrix have to send sensitive data through Microsoft's service when they have a service workflow of their own? I'm struggling to understand this!

Related documentation:

- http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-guides-how-tos/234780-how-push-notifications-work-why-sometimes-they-might-not.html

**EDIT**

If I set up a service of my own that Microsoft's push notification service interacts with... I can then make interactions on behalf of Podio... Is this normal practice?... I'm assuming that the lag of double dosing requests is going to be pretty useless for something like a messaging application.

I noticed that Android seems to also now have a middle man service... But I assume that having the choice means large companies who do not want to make a handshake with a third party company do not have to?

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you are asking for. Do you want to know whether it is necessary to set up some software on your own for using the Windows push service?

Comment: @Codor - Do my post alterations help for the question?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "they have told me that they currently will not support MPNS" - who is "they" - Microsoft?

Comment: The push notification service provider (Podio) - P.S @Codor Lol at your profile pic... man I've really gotta watch got.

Comment: In fact I don't understand what exactly this Podio is; it seems to be some third-party platform which can be accessed via an API by which push messeages to various mobile platforms (apparently to notify Podio apps) can be initiated. If Windows Phone is not supported, then there is no solution out of the box, I guess.